# All plots show up in notebook, but nbconvert notebook to html, only latest plotly express plots show up

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter, nbconvert, plotly-express

#### Background

- I'm working on a data challenge with 3GB data.
- I plotted about 10 plots using ploy-express in jupyter notebook.
- I didn't use `fig.show('notebook')` because it didn't work.
- I used `py.init_notebook_mode()`, all plots show up perfectly in notebook.
- They are simple plots each with 1 year of data, like `fig = px.line(df, x, y, ...)` then `fig.show()`

Everything works fine in notebook.

#### Problem

But until I tried to convert notebook into HTML file, only the latest 6 plots show up.

The first 4 plots have titles, legends, axes, background-canvas, when I hover over them the numbers pop up, but plots are not showing up, and each has an unhappy square face with "x"-looking eyes.

I tried:

- `!jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to html --template classic`
- or with `--execute`
- or without `--template`
- I increased notebook size changing `NotebookApp.max_buffer_size`, this didn't work.

I suspect this is a memory limit problem on `nbconvert` or HTML-related, because:

- when I reduce it to 6 plots, all of them show up
- when I added more plots, the first ones start to experience this problem, as if there is a memory limit.
- I think these are nbconvert documentation, but I don't see any 'limit' or 'max' when writing to HTML?

  - (https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/5.4/pdf/)
  - (https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html)

Did anyone solve the same problem?
Could someone help please?

#### Not Perfect Solution

- I have to click the legend then it shows up.
- But another graph disappears again.
- The total available is always 6 graphs like there is a limit of something

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally, I found out the all plots show up when I use Firefox, so I realize this is a render problem.

It turns out the default is `WegGL`, and I switched to `SVG`, by adding `render_mode='svg'`.

Wala, everything is solved.

Comment: This looks like a useful answer. Could you please clarify where you added `render_mode='svg'`? Could you show the full command / code?

Answer (score 0):

Just open the notebook in Jupyter-lab. From File menu select the option to export as HTML. It worked for me. I haven't found a way to make it work with nbconvert from command line. It would be good that you provide how you used render_mode='svg'. In my approach images were reduced and their java script was lost.